# Merging sub array with similar value using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var obj = [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[2,2]];
```

Needed **output** : `Output = [[0,0], [1,1], [2,2]];`

Need to merge with similar value is present in sub array.

Comment: Care to explain the logic behind the output? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: your output seems odd  ..

Comment: Plese give more explanation on the logic behind the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for unique values and then take the arrays with more than one unique item and concat it with only one unique item.

```js
var array = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]],
    unique = new Set(array.reduce((r, a) => r.concat(a), [])),
    result = array
        .filter(a => {
            if (a[0] !== a[1] && a.every(b => unique.has(b))) {
                a.forEach(b => unique.delete(b));
                return true;
            }
        })
        .concat(array.filter(a => {
            if (a.some(b => unique.has(b))) {
                a.forEach(b => unique.delete(b));
                return true;
            }
        }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```